# Can dispatch_async interrupt calling task

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Suppose I dispatch a task asynchronously to a queue:

```
{
    // we are on main queue

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      print("task B")
    });

    print("task A")

    // some long running work

    print("task A")

    // some long running work

    print("task A")
    ...
}
```

Can in any circumstance dispatched task interrupt the task from which it was dispatched? In other words, can it ever happen that "task B" gets printed before all "task A"-s are printed?

```
task A
task B
task A
task A
...
```

Or GCD will guarantee this:

```
task A
task A
task A
...
task B
```

Would it make any difference if the task were dispatched to the same queue from which dispatch_async was called?

Comment: BTW, your code snippet is running "some long running work" on the main queue. That's inadvisable. You never should run time consuming code on the main queue. I assume this was just an academic exercise, but just in case, remember, never block the main queue running some time consuming process in real apps. That's the sort of stuff that should be dispatched to background queues.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, question was only hypothetical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In other words, can it ever happen that "task B" gets printed before all "task A"-s are printed?

Absolutely it can happen. If you're dispatching asynchronously to either (a) a different queue; or (b) a concurrent queue (and the global queues are concurrent queues), you're explicitly requesting that they run concurrently with respect to each other.

The exact sequence of `A` and `B` log messages is a function of how time consuming the various tasks are, what the priority of the queues are, etc. But if you want `B` to not show up until after all of the `A` tasks, then you should explicitly control that behavior (notify blocks for dispatch groups, serial queues, barriers, etc.).

If you tell us what behavior you want to guarantee, we can tell you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. I'm trying to understand how exactly BrightFutures guarantees that callbacks are registered before task starts. https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures#providing-futures

Comment: But it appears that it does not guarantee that. It just saves result until callback is registered...

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, can it ever happen that "task B" gets printed before all "task A"-s are printed?

It's not impossible, and I wouldn't say that anything here is *guaranteed*. Asynchronous means you are telling the runtime "whenever, dude" (assuming that that is how you like to talk to the runtime).

If the `dispatch_async` is to the same queue as it is called on, *and* that queue is a *serial* queue, then your last scenario *is* guaranteed: we cannot start a new block on that queue until the current block has finished. (But DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT is *not* a serial queue.)

Comment: Quite likely, actually. Not unlikely at all. If you dispatch to a queue that happens to be empty, I'd expect the dispatch call itself to trigger running of the block, so that block would start running before the dispatch call even returns.

Comment: @gnasher729 Well, what happens around here is that newbies get confused exactly because the async block's code happens after the lines that follow it, so perhaps I've just gotten used to the idea that that's what most people see. :)

Comment: Thanks @matt. So if it were to dispatch from main to main queue than my scenario would be guaranteed because main queue is serial queue. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be "B" printed after all As, you can guarantee this:

```
// we are on main queue

print("task A")

// some long running work

print("task A")

// some long running work

print("task A")
...

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
^{
  print("task B")
});
```

Obviously this makes no sense, if the As are the long runners and B is a short runner.

Sorry, to me it looks like a bit you did not understand, what GCD is for. Maybe you want to tell us, what your real concrete scenario is and what you want to accomplish in that scenario.